# Databinding not working .. am I missing something?

Tags: xamarin, prism

I am using Prism on Xamarin Forms ......

I have followed the naming convention....
MainPage.xaml and MainPageViewModel.cs

I have the title property set and binding correctly along with some navigation commands but I am trying to bind to a list to allow the user to select an account to work on but the list is not populating in the UI.

In the view model I have a list:

```
public List<SiteDetail> SiteDetails;
```

In the view I am binding like such....

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListViewDownloadedServices" ItemsSource="{Binding SiteDetails}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextCell Text="{Binding CustomerNameField}"></TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

Everything I have seen refers to auto wiring of view model to view and the property is set in the XAML (prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True")

The data is in the list but the ListView is empty....

Any help, advice or guidance is GREATLY appreciated....

Comment: I'm late but for other people coming here. Your list does not implement `INotifyPropertyChange`. Even if you replace it by an `ObservableCollection`, you will have to re-assign it once your items are all loaded, not just add items.

Answer (score 1):

Change to
public List SiteDetails {set;get;}

Comment: Thanks but that did not work either...I have the appropriate entries in the XAML to include prism and to use the view model locator .. a title property works but the list is not binding for some reason....I have confirmed the list has items in it in debug

Comment: I even tried making it an ObservableCollection like so ...  public ObservableCollection<SiteDetail> SiteDetails { get; set; }

Comment: You can check my ListView example: https://github.com/vulcanlee/xamarin-forms-develop-notes-example/tree/master/XFListView